# MouseListeners and Tabbed Row Detection

Tags: java, actionlistener

Im new to Java and trying to get my head around the various functions, my current headache is MouseListeners

I have a JTabbedPane with three tabs each holding (JScrollPane plus a JTable) I now need to detect which row of which tab is being clicked and Im hitting problems.

Do I need to just put a single listener on the first pane and detect which tab has been selected? or do I put one on each JTable?

I tried the following code but for some reason when I run it it does error

```
standardTable.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
  @Override
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    JTabbedPane aPane = (JTabbedPane)e.getComponent();
    if(e.getClickCount()==2) {
      detectMouseClickRow(aPane, e);
    } // do this if double click
    if(e.getClickCount()==1) {
      detectSingleClick(aPane, e);
    } // Do this if its a single click
  }
});
```

When I run the above Netbeans alerts me to a problem but doesnt list where, so I ignore it and it errors at detectMouseClickRow(aPane, e); or its single click variant

**ClassCastException: javax.swing.JTable cannot be cast to javax.swing.JTabbedPane**

I could do with pointers because I'm prolly getting it wrong here and this is not the best method to use?

Comment: The message is self explanatory. So where in your code do you try to cast an Object to a JTabbedPane. The error tells you that the Object is a JTable so you should be casting the Object to a JTable. This makes sense since you add the listener to the JTable, not the JTabbedPane, so I'm not sure why you think the Object would be a JTabbedPane.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding an `MouseListener` on the standardTable which I assume is a `JTable`, now when retrieving components from `MouseEvent` e by `e.getComponent()`, you will get a `JTable`. So the casting `JTabbedPane aPane = (JTabbedPane)e.getComponent();` is not correct.
In fact, it should be `JTable aPane = (JTable)e.getComponent();`

Now, you could get the `JTabbedPane` from `JTable` by using `getParent()` depending on how you added `JTable` to the tabbed pane.

Comment: `I didn't see that part in the question` - you don't need to see it. Think about it for a minute. You suggested you add the MouseListener to the tabbed pane. Fine, so the user clicks on a tab, then what happens? The user hasn't had a change to even select a row in the table, so how can you get the currently selected row?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all Ive sorted it out slowly,
Yes there was an error on casting into JTabbedPane as it was a JTable
I would have deleted the question but I cannot find any way to do it,.

Sorry.

Comment: This is NOT answer answer. Delete the answer by clicking on the delete button. If you have additional comments to make, then edit the question with the comment. Keep all the information in one place. There is also a delete button for the question. It should be just under the "java ActionListener" tags that you specified for the question.